# how to view java web app like it is the latest build on a server?

Tags: java, iis, web-applications

I have been browsing tutorials but all are just gibberish since I do not know most of the terms. I am new to java and most of things I do are trial and error. We have this java web app that has around 4 solutions in which we checked in our codes using SVN. I can run the app in the local but not as a whole app. We can only see it as a whole if We build it in a server that says ....\hudson at the end. That is the only time I can see if my checked in codes are working well with other modules written in grails and in gwt. I was wondering if I can do this via local? Like how I do it in IIS for an asp .net web app. My prob is I can not see all frames when running it through IDE. I always make the mistake that I run the gwt project, it is working fine, then I run the grails working fine. but when I check it in the build, something gets broken. The same problem when I debug using cookies. If the cookie is being passed by a grail module toa gwt module, how can I do that if I can't run both at the same time? :(. The build in hudson is for everyone to see and I do not want to check in the codes I made before I am 100% it is working and nothing gets broken somewhere in the project.

Sorry total noob here. I do not even know what I need to install or if this is even possible? Below are the things I have:

> tomcat apache 6.0
>   JDK, JRE7

I believe I need to have the webapps folder inside C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0..
I can not see a very easy to follow tutorial anywhere. Can anyone pls help me? At least point me where to start? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hudson is a continuous integration server. Its goal is to check out the source code of your app, compile it, run unit tests and various other code quality checks, build the application, and potentialy deploy it.

The build/deploy is typically done using a build tool (Maven, Ant, Gradle, whatever) that uses a build file. You should be able to run this same build using this same build file, which must be in the SVN repo with the sources, and deploy the app on your own local server.

Now what I wonder is: this whold build procedure and infrastructure was not built magically. Someone in your company must have created it and documented it, or at least knows how it works. Why don't you ask this person how you're supposed to work?

Comment: yes someone built it, but that someone is on leave and not to mention in some other part of the world. I think our build tool is ANt, as I do that when using the jar file to another solution. I was just wondering why my other team mates never use this, they always view their build in hudson. Maybe, they are so proficient and so sure of their codes, unlike me. It would be nice if I can just read somewhere on how to as I am aware it could be a lengthy discussion.

Comment: I have uploaded a documentation on how to do this. pls see this link --> https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gECPuCOwiKGHoh8pBl1_ClPRrEY8B0mVawulgD4E7yM/edit